# Permission denied while running c file

Tags: permissions, gcc, c

```
ans@ans-HP-Compaq-6910p-GY837US-ABA:/media/study/coursera/IOT/Course2$ ls
hello.c~  helo.c   helo.c~
ans@ans-HP-Compaq-6910p-GY837US-ABA:/media/study/coursera/IOT/Course2$ gcc helo.c -o hello
ans@ans-HP-Compaq-6910p-GY837US-ABA:/media/study/coursera/IOT/Course2$ chmod u+x hello
ans@ans-HP-Compaq-6910p-GY837US-ABA:/media/study/coursera/IOT/Course2$ ./hello
bash: ./hello: Permission denied
ans@ans-HP-Compaq-6910p-GY837US-ABA:/media/study/coursera/IOT/Course2$
```

I am new to Ubuntu. I had just created a "hello world" program in c and tried to run it. But it is showing me

```
batch error: access denied.
```

I know this question has already been asked but I tried a lot of things and nothing is working for me.

Comment: Is `/media/study/coursea/IOT` a removable drive? if so, how is it formatted? Filesystems such as FAT or NTFS don't really support Unix-style permissions. Move your file(s) to your home directory and try again.

Comment: What file type is `hello` ? Please show the output of `file hello`, but make sure that you [edit] your question and paste it there as plain text, code formatted, instead of uploading another screenshot. Thanks.

Comment: See how it's mounted (read only?) with `mount`, but make sure that you http://askubuntu.com/posts/861041/edit your question and paste it there as plain text, code formatted, instead of uploading another screenshot. Thanks. –

Comment: Please don't use screenshots for terminal text. Instead, copy it, paste it into your question, select it, and press the `{}` button in the editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

copy your file to home folder or documents and try to run it

Comment: This would be better suited as a comment.

Comment: Can you tell me why this happens?

Comment: I am not sure but in Linux you can not run any programing file in media just from home folder or sub directory from root

Answer (score 0):

I had finally solved this.

1. I changed the file location from media to home
2. I rebuilt the code file `gcc helo.c -o hello`
3. I reran the program file `./ helo`