# Trying to run a c file in ubuntu multipass

Tags: permissions, multipass

I am using multipass to run a c code, and ive been changing where the file is but I keep getting the permission denied message

```
ubuntu@foo:~/C:/Users/andre/Documents/hello$ gcc hello.c -o hello                                                                    
hello.c:3:1: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Wimplicit-int]                                                                       
3| main(){                                                                                                                              
|^~~~                                                                                                                           
buntu@foo:~/C:/Users/andre/Documents/hello$ ./hello                                                                                   
bash: ./hello: Permission denied                                                                                                      ubuntu@foo:~/C:/Users/andre/Documents/hello$
```

Comment: `~/C:/Users/andre/Documents/hello` looks like a Windows path - if the file is located on a Windows filesystem (NTFS for example) then it may not support traditional Unix ideas of file permissions. See for example [Permission denied while running c file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/861041/permission-denied-while-running-c-file)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
chmod +x hello
```

Your generated file `hello.o` is not executable straightaway. To execute it, first turn on the executable flag.

Comment: Its not a new feature its a restriction on the filesystem that its been written to..

Comment: @steeldriver I am no C programmer so I removed the explanation.